# can't run maven project, build fail. Advice about Maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

i'm new in maven, i have no such time to study it at all.
i'm so sorry about my generic question.

i was programming my app with MVC JSF JPA and so on. I had problems with testing, i saw something about mocking, but i thing it is good for a team project, where i don't know all about project.

So i was searching something useful as "real case" test... i found arquillian! The faster and easier way to use arquillian is with maven. So i converted my project to a maven project.

i'm using the embedded version in Netbeans. After a clean, when i try to run my app, it return

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building myProject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:copy (default) @ myProject ---

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ myProject ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 2 resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ myProject ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module!
Compiling 73 source files to D:\OneDrive\Documenti\NetBeansProjects\myProject\target\classes
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 18.197s
Finished at: Fri Jun 17 09:32:44 CEST 2016
Final Memory: 32M/252M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project myProject: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type model.entities.MultimediaType_ -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This is the full stack trace:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project eWheel: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:796)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type model.entities.FeatureType_
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type model.entities.FeatureType_
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:469)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type model.entities.FeatureType_
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:407)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type model.entities.FeatureType_
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacFiler.checkNameAndExistence(JavacFiler.java:522)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacFiler.createSourceOrClassFile(JavacFiler.java:396)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacFiler.createSourceFile(JavacFiler.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.generateCanonicalModelClass(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.generateCanonicalModelClasses(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:403)
    ... 34 more


For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>myProject</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <!-- clip -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-alpha-1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <!-- clip -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
            <version>6.0</version>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- clip -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- clip -->
        <!-- We also need to configure Maven to run the JPA 2 annotation processor, 
        which is done simply by adding the Hibernate JPA metamodel generator as 
        a compile-only project dependency: -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!-- Weld EE embedded profile -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.4</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <!-- Weld EE embedded profile -->
        <!-- Glassfish embedded profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-glassfish-embedded</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
                    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-payara-embedded</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
                    <artifactId>payara-embedded-all</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.1.161</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <!-- Glassfish embedded profile -->
        <!-- JBoss AS profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-jbossas-managed</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <!-- JBoss AS profile -->
        <!-- remote container Boss AS 7.1 -->
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-jbossas-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <!-- remote container Boss AS 7.1 -->
        <!-- remote container Glassfish 3.1.2 -->
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-glassfish-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weld-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <!-- remote container Glassfish 3.1.2 -->
        <!-- remote container Payara -->
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-payara-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weld-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <!-- remote container payara-->
    </profiles>

    <!-- clip -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- clip -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- clip -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the maven output:

> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

This means you have to execute maven in this way to display the exception:

```
mvn -X
```

To do this in Netbeans, open project properties, select Actions and select the action you are executing. Add -X to the Execute Goals.

Rerun the test again and you will get the real exception in the output console.

This is looking strange and could cause problems:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

You are using an old shrinkwrap resolver in an alpha version!
Remove this dependency and just use this as a normal dependency. The version is already defined in the arquillian-bom.

```
 <dependency>  
  <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>  
  <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>  
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Check your persistence.xml. Is your entity defined in multiple persistence-units?

Comment: hummm... i had 2 PU, in persistence.xml (i added one for testing, then used resources and forget to remove). now i have some other errors, i will edit my question

Comment: Create a new question in SO.

Answer (score -2):

Right click on your project, select run as -> maven build... 
in goals, write:

`mvn -X clean install`

Found problem in your pom.xml

${project.build.directory}/endorsed

${project.build.directory} is a variable which you used but haven't defined

you can do it like this

```
<properties>
 <project.build.directory>your build directory here</project.build.directory>
</properties>
```

Comment: This is wrong, `project.build.directory` is defined by default to `target`.